# What to name my DOM elements for CSS purposes

Tags: css, structure

I'm having a very hard time assigning intelligent class names to my DOM elements.

I feel like the example below is something my CSS commonly devolves into:

```
<div class="article">
  <div class="title-container">
     <div class="title>Something fantastic</div>
     <div class="sub-title-controls">
        <div class="btn-like"></div>
        <div class="btn-google-plus-one"></div>
        <div class="btn-share"></div>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But then later I'll want to add a different style of "Share" button lower on the page.  So I end up doing:

```
<div class="article">
  <div class="title-container">
     <div class="title>Something fantastic</div>
     <div class="sub-title-controls">
        <div class="btn-like"></div>
        <div class="btn-google-plus-one"></div>
        <div class="btn-share-tiny"></div>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div>...More stuff...</div>
<div class="btn-share-big"></div>
```

Then things spiral out of control from there.

I guess what I'm looking for is: Is there any kind of Chicago Manual of Style for CSS?  Like when is a `<div>` really better described as a `<section>` or `<footer>`?    How do you intelligently name non-visual DIVs that serve as containers?

My CSS is a nightmare after 2 years of coding without structure.  Just about given up and gone all inline on this particular project.  :)  Tips appreciated.

Comment: If I could give one tip it would be "don't name your elements for CSS purposes". Name your elements to be semantic. i.e. to describe the *content*. Use CSS selectors to *bind* those semantics to your CSS rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SMACCS](http://smacss.com/) is style guide for CSS, and might be exactly what you're looking for. You can buy it, or alternatively much of the content is available free on the site.

Additionally, [BEM](http://bem.info/method/) is a framework developed by the guys at [Yandex](http://www.yandex.com/), which I found useful reading and is used (somewhat) by [InuitCSS](http://inuitcss.com/), which I personally am keen on.

Comment: I think this is what I'm probably looking for.  Looks like I've got some reading to do.  Thanks Joshua!

Answer (score 1):

You should find some answers here, in this article titled: [What Makes For a Semantic Class Name?](http://css-tricks.com/semantic-class-names/).

In a nutshell, when you can, use the new HTML5 tags:

```
<header></header>
<article></article>
<aside></aside>
<footer></footer>
```

for your example, it would be better to do something like this :

```
<div class="btn-share"></div>
...
<div class="btn-share bigBtn"></div>
```

and only change the size in the bigBtn class.

Comment: @Cana I read the original link you sent about Semantic vs Non-Semantic - it was very helpful!  It didn't answer all of my questions, but it helped.